# Oracle Trigger with two tables

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to build a trigger to fix some kind of bug inside a Program. There are different rows in t2 and the program merges selected ones together in t1 and gives them one single id. So n-rows in t2 are 1 row in t1. Now i want to restrict that you can put multiple rows in t2 together when the customer in t2 is different. When this happens the trigger should write a message in a text field in t1.
So far I got this:

```html
create or replace
trigger multiple after insert on t1 
referencing new as new 
for each row
declare count1 number;

begin
select count(distinct t2.customer)
into count1
from t2
where  trim(t2.id)= trim(:new.id);
  

  if    count1 >=2  
  then 
 
 :new.txt_field :='Please delete.';
end if;
end;
```

But now there is a problem the t2.id is null at this point and will be updated a step after in the program. It looks like the program inserts the merged row in t1 with the t1.id and after that it updates the t2.id for every row.
Anyone got an idea how i can solve this?

Greetings

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario with some test data?

Comment: Why not put the trigger on t2?

Comment: @Chandonne ddl structure needed for t1 and t2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello sorry for the late answer and the unclear question.
I solved the question myself.
I created a staging table with a trigger and this works fine for me.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

question is not clear but as I understand you have many to one relation in t2 -> t1 and you want one row should insert in t1 when there is multiple row inserted on t2. solution for this put statement level trigger on t2 that you need to remove for each row keyword; also you need to apply internal check in trigger if this record is available or not in t1.